# Beamer nested enumerate collapse

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I have a long list of  nested research (sub)questions as items for my thesis presentation which do not fit on one page. I did this by nesting up to three enumerate lists together. I would like to try to make the subquestions collapsible, such that only the  past "first row" items and the current first, second and third row are visible. Otherwise, these rows should be collapsed for space saving. Anyone knows if this is possible?

Kind regards,

Marten

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap the secondary enumerations in a `onlyenv` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item question 1
        \begin{onlyenv}<1>
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item question 1b
                \item question 2b
                \item question 3b
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{onlyenv}

        \item question 2
        \begin{onlyenv}<2>
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item question 1b
                \item question 2b
                \item question 3b
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{onlyenv}

        \item question 3
        \begin{onlyenv}<3>
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item question 1b
                \item question 2b
                \item question 3b
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{onlyenv}

    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```